# Need to determine if a list of points are all part of the same circle in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, geometry

VB.NET

My data is coming from an exported DXF file from various cad packages. When a circular arc (defined as a part of a true circle) is exported it is sometimes exported as a bunch of line segments rather than a circular arc.

I have a list of points and I am trying to guess if they were derived from the same circle. Basically I iterate through all the points and use a method to find the center point of a circle from three points. My intention was to compare all the calculated center points generated and make a determination if they are close to each other.

My first thought was that I could check to see if the center points are all equal but they have slight differences between them because of rounding and the underlying estimating routine that generates the point in the first place (I have no control over that).

MY second was to check the standard deviation of the x and y values of the circumference points and compare that against the standard deviation of the x,y of the centers and make some judgement from that. VB.net does not seem to have a native stdev function and I am sometimes a bit lazy.

Does anybody have a simple idea on how to determine if a list of points are all from the same circle?

Here are my functions:

To determine the center of a circle given three points:

```
    Public Function getCenter(p1 As Point2D, p2 As Point2D, p3 As Point2D) As Point2D
        Dim yDelta_a As Double = p2.Y - p1.Y
        Dim xDelta_a As Double = p2.X - p1.X
        Dim yDelta_b As Double = p3.Y - p2.Y
        Dim xDelta_b = p3.X - p2.X
        Dim center As New Point2D
        Dim aSlope As Double = yDelta_a / xDelta_a
        Dim bSlope As Double = yDelta_b / xDelta_b
        center.X = (aSlope * bSlope * (p1.Y - p3.Y) + bSlope * (p1.X + p2.X) - aSlope * (p2.X + p3.X)) / (2 * (bSlope - aSlope))
        center.Y = -1 * (center.X - (p1.X + p2.X) / 2) / aSlope + (p1.Y + p2.Y) / 2

        Return center

    End Function
```

And then to iterate the list of points and get a collection of centers. FYI...This function received a list of lines that have endpoints that are points so I do a bit of iterating to get all the correct points.

```
    Public Function MakesCircle(lines As List(Of Line))
        Dim points As New List(Of Point2D)
        If lines.Count < 2 Then
            Return False
        Else
            //Get points from lines
            For i As Int16 = 0 To lines.Count - 2
                points.Add(lines(i).StartPoint)
            Next
            points.Add(lines.Last.StartPoint)
        End If

        //"Prime the pump" for the center calculation loop
        Dim centers As New List(Of Point2D)
        Dim a As Point2D = points(0)
        Dim b As Point2D = points(1)
        Dim c As Point2D = points(2)

        //Calc all the centers
        For i As Int16 = 3 To lines.Count - 1
            centers.Add(getCenter(a, b, c))
            a = b
            b = c
            c = points(i)
        Next
        //This is where I need logic to determine if the points all actually belong to the same circle
        Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: Off top of head (so may be flawed!): find points with max and min y values, and points with max and min x values. calculate an 'average' centre point. then calc std dev dist of all points from this centre?

Comment: How much data is your function expected to work from? Are the circles originating from computer generated circles (and thus the only error is from rounding), or is it from measured or user input of some kind?

Comment: Three or more points up to a few hundred. My data is coming from an exported DXF file from various cad packages. When a circular arc (defined as a part of a true circle) is exported it is sometimes exported as a bunch of line segments rather than a circular arc. DXF conversion routines can also export splines as a bunch of line segments (called polylines) as well. I need to distinguish the difference between a polyline that was generated from a circle and a polyline that was generated from a spline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GraphicsPath` object to find this out. -not tested-
I figured you would be able to construct a `Rectangle Structure` based on the data coming in (x,y,w,h) then this make-shift algorithm would do for you.

```
Private Function areAllPointsInEllipsis(ellipsis As Rectangle, pts() As Point) As Boolean
  Dim result As Boolean 
  Using gp As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
    gp.AddEllipsis(ellispsis)
    result = pts.All(Function(pt) gp.IsVisible(pt))
  End Using
  Return result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was generate all the distances from the average center point to each of the points that make up the circumference. Find the max and min distances. They you can use a threshold of a percentage of the radius - a kind of eccentricity measurement. If the difference between the max and min falls below 1% of the radius then I call it a circle.